# What makes blocks in blockchain secure if we already have the hash?

Tags: blockchain

What I understand about blockchain is that:
Blocks are secured by the hash.
Transactions are secured by the markle-tree.

Does this mean that the markle-tree is not involved at all in securing the blocks?

If so, what prevents us from changing the transactions if we know the hash of older blocks in the chain?

Please note that I'm assuming that we are using a blockchain with only one node. And I want to know how hard it is to hack the blockchain in one node. Because as far as i understand, the hashing alone is very secure, but distributing the blockchain on multiple nodes will make it even more secure.

Comment: Hi Wawa, welcome to SO. This is an interesting question, but I am going to close it because it is better asked on [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/). The question is also very broad, because each crypto uses a different algo to secure the chain.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it belongs on [Bitcoin](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: If there is only one node, then that is not really a blockchain.  It is just a centralized database with extra steps.  There is no point in using a blockchain unless you are going to have several nodes that don't trust each other.  If you want to trust some central authority, just use a regular database.

Answer (score 0):

Blocks are secured with the proof of work. The proof of work is a measure related to how many hashes (on average) it would take to get a block hash equal to the network target value. The lower the target value, the more work was done on the block, and the harder it is to change or "hack" the data in the block and still remain a valid block (because you must do the work again).

The merkle root is just a way to represent all of the transactions in the block in a single hash value, which is part of the data that is hashed to produce the block hash. If you change any of the transaction data, it will produce a different merkle root, and that will make the resulting block hash different too, and now the proof of work must be done again before the block would be considered valid.

Now, with only one node, it does not matter. If you are able to change the data in a block and rehash that block with a new valid hash (one that is equal to or lower than the network target value), you have a new block, but the node will reject it because it already has that block. You must mine the next block also before anyone else because one of the consensus rules is that the longest valid chain always wins.

Having only one node running means that node can be changed by the person who is running it, possibly without anyone else knowing. This might remove certain rules that you thought we're being followed, which could reverse one of your transactions, so it is good to run your own node to make sure the rules are being followed.